# Get the index of the first and last value enclosed by a region

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, binary-search, pytables

I have a sorted pytables table of integer values which might contain duplicates, and a region denoted by a start and end value (end exclusive).

I want to find the index of the value which is closest to the beginning of the region AND the index of the value which is closest to the end of the region. The resulting indices must be enclosed by the region. Example:

```
region = (35, 56)
table_data = [4, 6, 18, 18, 30, 37, 37, 49, 54, 56, 80, 84]

result: (5, 8)
```

This sounds like something that can be solved with a binary search-like algorithm, but I haven't figured out how to do it yet.

Since this piece of code may be performed thousands of times on very large pytables tables, performance is important. Preferably, if its possible, the start and end indices values should be computed in the same loop.

Can anyone help?

Edit:

I'm actually not working with arrays, but with pytables tables. So answers that suggests using the bisect module are not going to work. Rows can be accessed by tables[index] (via the table's getslice method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple use binsearch to find

- smallest value bigger than your lower bound
- biggest value smaller than your upper bound

The complexity is `O(lgn)` since these are two completely independent problems.